# How to print in a single row in a loop?

Tags: fortran

Suppose I have a Fortran program which includes the following loop:

```
do i=1, 10
  print *, i
enddo
```

The output of this will be like

```
1
2
...
10
```

How can I write these values to a single line, like in the following?

```
1 2 ... 10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways, two that come to mind immediately are shown in the following little program

```
$ cat loop.f90
Program loop
  Implicit None
  Integer :: i
  Write( *, * ) 'First way - non-advancing I/O'
  Do i = 1, 10
     Write( *, '( i0, 1x )', Advance = 'No' ) i
  End Do
  Write( *, * ) ! Finish record
  Write( *, * ) 'Second way - implied do loop'
  Write( *, * ) ( i, i = 1, 10 )
End Program loop
$ gfortran -std=f2003 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all loop.f90 
$ ./a.out
 First way - non-advancing I/O
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
 Second way - implied do loop
           1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10
$
```

The first method. non-advancing I/O, suppresses the end of record marker being written, which is normally a new line, but does require an explicit format. The second, implied do loop, doesn't require a format, but is less flexible.

BTW in English they are normally called "loops"

Comment: I like the first way best - depending on the compiler, the second way may split the output onto several lines.