# Output from multiple iterations of a loop to a single line

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is my code:

```
Program Output_Format

Implicit none

Integer::k
Integer,parameter:: Br_nn_mre = 11
Character(56),parameter:: FMT_01 = '(1x,"NN_0",i0)'
Character(56),parameter:: FMT_02 = '(1x,"NN_",i0)'


Open( 15 , File = 'Output.txt' , Status = 'Unknown' , Action = 'Write' )

    Do k = 1 , Br_nn_mre

       If ( k < 10) Write( 15 , FMT_01 ) k
       If ( k > 9 ) Write( 15 , FMT_02 ) k

    End do

Close( 15 , Status = 'Keep' )


End Program Output_Format
```

The content of `Output.txt` is:

```
  NN_01
  NN_02
  ....
  NN_11
```

My intention is to get this content in `Output.txt` all in a single line:

```
NN_01 NN_02 ... NN_11
```

What kind of change to `FMT_01` and `FMT_02` must I make if I want to get that?

Comment: Yes, that is what i want to get.

Comment: Then you probably want to use [non-advancing output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41464997/3157076).  Note that there is no change to the format you can make to have the output you desire: your write statements always write to separate records.

Comment: How to use impiied do loop in this case with `if` conditions?

Comment: You needn't use the implied-do approach (from the answer there) in your case as you have an explicit format.  Change your write statements to `Write( 15 , FMT_01, advance='no') k` and `Write( 15 , FMT_02, advance='no') k`.

Comment: That is clear but i do not now how to use `if` with implied do loops.

Comment: In answer i learn how to use `advance = 'no'` and i got the result in one line. Noq i want to learn how can i do same thing with implied do loop and i  ask you for solution?

Comment: Ah, understood.  I think you can ask a separate question about that (referencing this one for context), explicitly focussing on the "how do I use an implied-do when there's the conditional" aspect. However, I suspect the answer may well be "don't: just use your explicit loop with non-advancing output".  [As comments on your code here, though: you don't actually need to use `fmt_01` and `fmt_02` and the conditional on `k` to get the output you want.  You can use format `(" NN_",I2.2)` for both cases (0<k<100).]

Comment: Add a trailing `$` to your `FORMAT` strings: `FMT_01 = '(1X,"NN_0",i0,$)'`

Comment: I disagree with the assertion that this question is an exact duplicate of the one mentioned.  The question here is how to modify the `FORMAT` strings.  The proposed duplicate does not do that.